# How to call a function inside an append?

Tags: jquery

I have an append

```
$("#accordionWiki").append("
  <div class='panel panel-default' id='headingWiki_"+i+"'>
   <div class='panel-body'> FUNCTION </div>
  </div>"
);
```

and a function like

```
function wikiText() {
  $.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&callback=?", {..
}
```

I tried to put wikiText(); inside the append where I wrote **FUNCTION** but I got something wrong, maybe concatenation, not sure.

Comment: `"+wikiText()+"`?

Comment: @guradio i will try again but I am pretty sure with all my tries I did it and it didn't work

Comment: what will `wikiText()` do? can you show what is in the function, what do you return there?

Comment: AS per @caramba, we need a bit more info on what you are trying to do as there are likely other better and more structured / robust approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't append the results of your function because you use a ajax call in that function which is asynchronous, just call it after the append:

```
 function(data) {
              $("#accordionWiki").empty();
              $.each(data.query.search, function(i, item) {
                $("#accordionWiki").append("<div class='panel panel-default'><div class='panel-heading' role='tab' id='headingWiki_"+i+"'><h3 class='panel-title'><a role='button' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordionWiki' href='#collapseWiki_"+i+"' aria-expanded='true' aria-controls='collapseWiki_"+i+"'>"+ item.title.replace(" ", "_") + "<br><small>" + item.snippet + "</small></a></h3></div><div id='collapseWiki_"+i+"' class='panel-collapse collapse' role='tabpanel' aria-labelledby='headingWiki_"+i+"'><div class='panel-body'></div></div></div></div>");
                 wikiText('headingWiki_'+i);
              });
```

change  the wiki function to update only the current element in the loop:

```
function wikiText(el) {
            $el = $('#'+el);
            $.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&callback=?", {
                page: $(e.relatedTarget).find('h4').text()
            }, function(data) {
              var markup = data.parse.text["*"];
              var blurb = $('<div></div>').html(markup);
              blurb.find('a').each(function() {
                  $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
              });
              blurb.find(".mw-editsection, #toc, .noprint, .thumb, img, table").remove();
              $(el).find(".panel-title").html(articleName);
               $(el).find(".panel-body").html($(blurb));
               $(el).find(".panel-body").promise().done(function(){
                $('.panel-body *[style]').attr('style', '');
                 $(el).find("table").addClass("table table-striped table-hover table-responsive").wrapAll('<div class="table"/>');
                 $(el).find("table, td, tr, th").removeAttr("style");
                 $(el).find("img").addClass("img-responsive");
                 $(el).find(".panel-body").css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1.0});
                saveWiki();
                 $(el).find(".panel-body div *").attr("contenteditable", "true");
              });
            });
          };
```

Comment: why did you put wikiText('headingWiki_'+i); ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
function wikiText() {
   var returnHTML=""+ 
 "<div class='panel panel-default' id='headingWiki_"+i+"'> "+
  " <div class='panel-body'> FUNCTION </div> "+
 " </div>";

 return returnHTML;
}

$("#accordionWiki").append(wikiText());
```

I guess you need your I as parameter for wikiText(I) function

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("body").append("<div class='panel panel-default' id='headingWiki_'><div class='panel-body'> "+wikiText()+" </div></div>"
);

function wikiText() {
  return "asd";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Something like this